# Find out what file does a program attempt to read

Tags: windows, file, winamp

I've got third party Winamp plug-in in windows, that should be able to load its datafile.

The datafile is located in same folder as the plug-in, but can not be found. My idea is that plug-in searches in some pre-defined path. So I need somehow to find out what file read attempt is done to place file in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use Process Monitor from Sysinternals suite (http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb896645)

Set up filters to watch only the examined program and look for 'CreateFile' operations, which are also read attempts.

Comment: -1. Not exactly true. Is possible call CreateFile without reading.

Comment: @Xearinox, my point was that all readings will be CreateFile, not otherwise. Or is it possible to attempt read without CreateFile call?

Comment: First, yes is possible read without CreateFile using Nt/ZwReadFile. Also file may will be open with CreateFile without read attept, etc. for exclusive lock.

Comment: So, how should I improve the answer to make it correct? What is the full list of possible operations that may be invoked at file read attempt?

Comment: @Xearinox could you please suggest on how to improve the answer?